# IDA (х64) - Преобразование ассемблерного кода в псевдокод

Tags: c++, ассемблер, дизассемблирование, псевдокод, ida-pro

Здравствуйте. У меня следующая проблема - при преобразовании ассемблерного кода в псевдокод в IDA без каких либо изменений получаем следующее:

Ассемблер:

```
.text:00000000006A470C sub_6A470C      proc near               ; DATA XREF: .rdata:off_CE6330o
.text:00000000006A470C                                         ; .pdata:000000002998E6DCo ...
.text:00000000006A470C                 push    rbx
.text:00000000006A470E                 mov     r8d, cs:TlsIndex
.text:00000000006A4715                 mov     rax, gs:58h
.text:00000000006A471E                 lea     rbx, __ImageBase
.text:00000000006A4725                 mov     rax, [rax+r8*8]
.text:00000000006A4729                 mov     r11, rcx
.text:00000000006A472C                 mov     ecx, 7D18h
.text:00000000006A4731                 movsxd  r10, dword ptr [rcx+rax]
.text:00000000006A4735                 mov     r9, r10
.text:00000000006A4738                 movsxd  r8, dword_1E8EC90[rbx+r10*4]
.text:00000000006A4740                 imul    r9, 3E8h
.text:00000000006A4747                 add     r9, r8
.text:00000000006A474A                 lea     eax, [r8+1]
.text:00000000006A474E                 mov     dword_1E8EC90[rbx+r10*4], eax
.text:00000000006A4756                 lea     rax, asc_B69910
.text:00000000006A475D                 mov     rva qword_226F890[rbx+r9*8], rax
.text:00000000006A4765                 mov     eax, [r11+10h]
.text:00000000006A4769                 mov     rcx, [rdx+0A90h]
.text:00000000006A4770                 cmp     [rcx+0A0h], eax
.text:00000000006A4776                 setz    al
.text:00000000006A4779                 add     dword_1E8EC90[rbx+r10*4], 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00000000006A4782                 pop     rbx
.text:00000000006A4783                 retn
.text:00000000006A4783 sub_6A470C      endp
```

Псевдокод:

```
bool __fastcall sub_6A470C(__int64 a1, __int64 a2)
{
    __int64 v2; // r10@1
    __int64 v3; // r8@1
    bool result; // al@1

    v2 = *(_DWORD *)(*(_QWORD *)(*MK_FP(__GS__, 88i64) + 8i64 * (unsigned int)TlsIndex) + 32024i64);
    v3 = *(int *)((char *)&_ImageBase.unused + 4 * v2 + (_QWORD)dword_1E8EC90);
    *(int *)((char *)&_ImageBase.unused + 4 * v2 + (_QWORD)dword_1E8EC90) = v3 + 1;
    *(_QWORD *)((char *)&_ImageBase.unused + 8 * (v3 + 1000 * v2) + (_QWORD)&qword_226F890[-524288]) = L"bool __fastcall sub_6A470C(__int64 a1, __int64 a2)";
    result = *(_DWORD *)(*(_QWORD *)(a2 + 2704) + 160i64) == *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 16);
    --*(int *)((char *)&_ImageBase.unused + 4 * v2 + (_QWORD)dword_1E8EC90);
    return result;
}
```

Если же нажать ПКМ на __ImageBase (по адресу 0x6A471E), выбрать Manual... (Alt+F1) и в открывшемся окне нажать OK, при этом ничего не изменяя, получаем следующее:

Псевдокод:

```
bool __fastcall sub_6A470C(__int64 a1, __int64 a2)
{
  __int64 v2; // r10@1
  __int64 v3; // r8@1
  bool result; // al@1

  v2 = *(_DWORD *)(*(_QWORD *)(*MK_FP(__GS__, 88i64) + 8i64 * (unsigned int)TlsIndex) + 32024i64);
  v3 = dword_1E8EC90[v2 + 0x100000];
  dword_1E8EC90[v2 + 0x100000] = v3 + 1;
  qword_226F890[v3 + 1000 * v2] = (__int64)L"bool __fastcall sub_6A470C(__int64 a1, __int64 a2)";
  result = *(_DWORD *)(*(_QWORD *)(a2 + 2704) + 160i64) == *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 16);
  --dword_1E8EC90[v2 + 0x100000];
  return result;
}
```

Как видно, код стал более-менее читабельный.
В чем суть проблемы ? Возможно ли написать скрипт и поправить эти места ?
Данная проблема возникает по сути если при загрузки исполняемого файла включить загрузку HEADER'a файла.

Так же в логе IDA есть следующие ошибки, но при исправлении их проблема не устраняется:

```
1E8EC90: using guessed type int dword_1E8EC90[];
226F890: using guessed type __int64 qword_226F890[];
299655C8: using guessed type int TlsIndex;
```

Был бы очень благодарен хотя бы за подсказку в какую сторону копать.

P.S. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А какого типа __ImageBase у вас там, кстати? И это же какая-то глобальная структура, да?

Comment: `__ImageBase` имеет тип `HINSTANCE__`, указывает на начало исполняемого файла в памяти: "`400000 __ImageBase     db  4Dh`".

Comment: Хм. Попробуйте __ImageBase сделать обычным dd, а не структурой, может прокатит?

Comment: К сожалению нет, не помогло, все осталось так же. Добавил в тему еще ошибки которые есть в логе IDA, возможно натолкнет на какие либо идеи.

Comment: Тогда хрен его знает. HEXRAYS бывает иногда лажает :-(

Comment: Согласен :( Только вот если не грузить HEADER файла, то все анализируется более-менее нормально. А т.к. загрузил с ним и часть кода уже разобрал (вручную), то как-то не очень хочется из-за этой проблемы делать все с самого начала (грузить без HEADER'a), сижу и пытаюсь понять в чем проблем, возможно я что-то не понимаю либо не доглядел.